# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__product_product.brand_id

Tags: python, django

I am preparing an ecommerce project in Django. Now I'm trying to change some things
When I run the `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands, I get an error that I can't understand.

error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__product_product.brand_id
```

models.py

```
class Brand(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='brand')
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=15, unique=True)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/%Y/%m/%d/')
  detail = models.TextField()
  keywords = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  price = models.FloatField()
  #brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Markon', verbose_name='Brand (Default: Markon)')
  brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='Markon')
  sale = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Sale (%)")
  bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Did you by any chance used a `OneToOneField` before, or set `unique=True` in the `brand` field?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes i tried both

Comment: Could you check what type the `brand_id` field in your `new__product_product` table is? There is one comment line with a brand field definition and one non-comment line. Maybe there was a change which the migration should capture?!

Comment: The default value for your `brand` field seems not to be a valid ID of a brand but a string: `default='Markon'`. This is invalid, as long as your `Brand` model is using the defaulr primary key field provided by django.

Comment: @sohretaga: likely the migration where it is failing still uses a `OneToOneField`, hence the error...

Comment: @JanMalte I don't know how to fix

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Are you talking about the cache?

Comment: You don't need to know how to fix it, but we need the information about the current database structure (type of the brand_id field) to give you some help